# Clear all injections in PhantomJs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Is there any possibility to remove all injections provided by:

```
phantom.injectJs(scriptName);
```

I would like to clean up phantom after my qunit test finish.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you reload the web page without injections, I do not believe you can remove script injections. I would set some sort of boolean flag to determine if your tests have completed and then reload the page without the injections if true.

Also, you can programmatically choose whether a script gets injected based on application logic. For example, if you only want to inject jQuery onto a couple of pages, but not all, you can create a state machine for tracking which page your script is on and determine based on the current state whether to inject jQuery or not.